# How to force LaTeX to error when an \include file is missing/misspelled?

Tags: pdftex, errors, external-files, include, compilation-error

The only file which was meant to be compiled in my `Main.tex` was specified by the following line:

```latex
\include{transformtaion}
```

It was compiled without any error using the following command:

```latex
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode Main.tex
```

However, the generated PDF file was empty. After investing a large amount of time, I learned that the problem is with misspelling of the file, i.e. **transfor*mta*ion** instead of **transfor*mat*ion**.
The question is how to force the compilation process to give a compile-time error which indicates the misspelling problem.

Comment: Get rid of `interaction=nonstopmode`.

Comment: @IanThompson that probably does not do much `\include` does not complain if the file is not found. `\input` does.

Comment: @daleif --- I didn't know that. I'd still get rid of nonstopmode, though.

Comment: @IanThompson This is not the solution. No error will be shown with or without `interaction=nonstopmode`.

Comment: If you are an AUCTeX/Emacs user, this error should not happend. When inputing files for input or include, you are prompted with a list of valid files. with auto-completion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is a (maybe not so great) feature of `\include` to just tell you on the terminal that the file does not exist.  You get a one-liner like this:

```
No file transformtaion.tex.
```

which is quite hard to spot if you're not looking for it.

Redefining the internals of `\include` is not advisable, so you can use the `include` hooks to explicitly check for the existence of the file, and error accordingly:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\mkfilename#1{%
  \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{#1}\relax\else#1/\fi}
\AddToHook{include/before}%
  {\IfFileExists{\mkfilename\CurrentFilePath\CurrentFile}{}
     {\GenericError{}{Error: File \mkfilename\CurrentFilePath\CurrentFile.tex not found!}{\@gobble}{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\include{transformtaion}
\end{document}
```

then you'll see an error:

```latex
! Error: File transformtaion.tex not found!.

Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.15 \include{transformtaion}

?
```

---

In older releases (before 2020-10-01), without the built-in support for `include` hooks, you can use `filehook` and `currfile`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filehook}
\usepackage{currfile}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginOfIncludes
  {\IfFileExists{\currfiledir\currfilebase.tex}{}
     {\GenericError{}{Error: File \currfiledir\currfilebase.tex not found!}{\@gobble}{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\include{transformtaion}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `Undefined control sequence. \AddToHood`; Is it related to my document class which is `report`? If this is the case, what is the alternative solution?

Comment: @Alish No, `report` is fine.  You have an older LaTeX distribution (pre 2020).  I added an alternative for older releases.  I'd recommend an update though

Comment: Now the error appears regardless of whether or not the file exists.

Comment: @Alish I just tested with a file named `transformtaion.tex` and it works.  Can you show me the `.log`, please (you can upload it to pastebin or something like that)

Comment: Your solution works when compilation is done through the terminal. I got the error only when I used texstudio for compilation, which uses exactly the same command, i.e.:`pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode Main.tex`

Comment: @Alish That is odd... Are you sure TeXStudio is actually building the document, rather than using a cached version somehow (just wild guessing).  If it is building the document, there should be a `Main.log` file in there.  Can you upload it somewhere so I can take a look?

Comment: This is the [Main.log](https://pastebin.com/4jHz6JzD).

Comment: @Alish Sorry, I missed the case of files in subfolders.  The code should work now.  Aside: you seem to have forgotten to add `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` to the code in your document.